# Convert String to Date using PowerShell

Tags: string, date, powershell, datetime

I have a date as string in the the following form:

```
July 27th, 2016
December 3rd, 2014
August 1st, 1998
March 2nd, 1979
```

How do I convert the date to the following using PowerShell

```
2016-07-27
2014-12-03
1998-08-01
1979-03-02
```

Answer (score 2):

I would opt for `ParseExact()` with some regex to remove all th's, rd's, st's.
Than you just have to use correct format in `ToString()`

**EDIT** updating the code based on @JosefZ suggestion.

```
foreach ($date in @(
    'July 27th, 2016'
    'December 3rd, 2014'
    'August 1st, 1998'
    'March 2nd, 1979'
)) {
    $clean = $date -replace '(st|nd|rd|th),'
    $dateObject = [datetime]::ParseExact($clean, 'MMMM d yyyy', [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
    # Apparently, this works too ...    
    $dateObject = [datetime]$clean  
    $dateObject.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
}
```

Comment: `$dateObject = [datetime]$clean` should suffice. For my locale, `ParseExact` raises _Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."_. Replace 3rd argument `$null` with `[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the method shown by @Andrii-Matus, @BartekB, the following is another way to achieve the same thing.

```
$date_str = @(
    'July 27th, 2016'
    'December 3rd, 2014'
    'August 1st, 1998'
    'March 2nd, 1979'
)

foreach ($date in $date_str){
    $newformat = $date -replace '(st|nd|rd|th),'
    get-date $newformat -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d"
}
```